# Javascript "undefined" output issue

Tags: javascript, forms, select

I have all of this code that creates new divs and adds innerHTML.  Within that, I want to add dropdowns with  generated from an XML file.  I'm having an issue with dynamically creating the  tags inside of inner.HTML.

Now, this is all dynamic and the user is supposed to add new elements as needed.  So, as a work around, I have a bunch of var values that process along with each other so things correspond to the same ID's.

```
var opselectCounterA = '1';
var opselectCounterB = '1';
var selectCounter = '1';
```

The  tag that I want to add is also within an inner.HTML.

```
something.innerHTML = "<select id='partSelect" + (selectCounter++) + "'>" + (loadOp) + "</select>";

var selectIDA = "partSelect" + opselectCounterA++;
var selectIDB = "partSelect" + opselectCounterB++;
var loadOp = selectIDA.addOption();

function addOption(){

    selectIDB.innerHTML = "<option>Please work.</option>";

}
```

Whenever this processes on my HTML page, it shows between the  tags as "undefined".

Why for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few things wrong with your code (even though I am only seeing a portion of it).

Regarding the line `var loadOp = selectIDA.addOption();`...

1. When this line executes javascript tries to execute a function named `addOption()` which exists on the `selectIDA` object. However the `selectIDA` variable is actually a string that doesn't have a `addOption()` function. Because javascript doesn't find a function named `addOption()` on the `selectIDA` object, it sets the value of loadOp to `undefined`.
2. Additionally, even if you had written `var loadOp = addOption();` instead, the value of `loadOp` would still be undefined because `addOption()` doesn't return any values.

Perhaps you should try something more along these lines...

```
// Function takes a select element and some text as args
// then adds option elements to the select
function addOption(select, optionText) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.innerText = optionText;
  select.appendChild(option);
}


var opselectCounterA = 1;
opselectCounterA++;

var selectIDA = "partSelect" + opselectCounterA;

// Create the select element
var selectA = document.createElement("select");
selectA.setAttribute("id", selectIDA);

// Add options to that select element
addOption(selectA, "My First Option");
addOption(selectA, "My Second Option");
addOption(selectA, "My Third Option");

// Add the select element to the body
document.body.appendChild(selectA);​
```

**View the working example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nxezs/**

Comment: So, I'm reading up on things and I'm having difficulty differentiating what is Javascript and which is done in the HTML DOM.  Are they so intertwined in their application that they're symbiotic?  The issue what I was looking for reference on things like create.Element and innerHTML in Javascript libraries, but came to find out they're DOM properties?

What's the significance of putting "select, optionText" in the addOption brackets?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't really the place to teach these fundamental concepts. Here are a few really good books that you should take the time to read. http://www.amazon.com/dp/1590595335/ http://www.amazon.com/dp/0596101996/

Comment: I should say.. that "a StackOverflow comment thread" isn't the place to teach this stuff. There are lots of great resources online too. Just search for "Javascript DOM tutorial".